# Unable to publish BuildingSceneLayer from revit file in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, revit

Unable to publish a Building Scene Layer in ArcGIS Pro version-2.3 application running on Windows-64 bit operating system, from a Revit file.

When I try to do so I get:

> Your portal does not support publishing this dataset type

How to check and modify the dataset types are supported in the portal if possible?

> The revit file was downloaded from example from the Autodesk Revit website example given below:

[http://www.autodesk.com/revit-rac-basic-sample-project-2018-enu?_ga=2.195217900.1145496523.1548998945-1799372949.1548830014][1]

The version of ArcGIS Portal being used is 10.6

Comment: I can't find anything that explicitly states revit is _not_ supported in Enterprise 10.6, but it seems revit was introduced as a supported type in Pro 2.2. ArcGIS Pro 2.2 more closely align with Enterprise 10.6.1. Are you able to upgrade to 10.6.1 and try it there?

Comment: Of course you could convert the revit file to multipatch or features inside a fGDB and publish from that....

Comment: Thank you,I will try upgrading to 10.6.1 and try to publish it.

Comment: @KHibma ,by your previous comment did you mean to convert each layer in the revit dataset such as roofs to mutlipatch feature class and publish individual layers as Scene Layers?,can you please suggest steps for the same if i am wrong.